# Undefined index when try to remember form input

Tags: php, forms, post, input

I'm having a form and I want to remember the input after a submission failed.

I cant figure out what is going wrong.

I'm using this:

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['isb-vraag1'] = $_POST['isb-vraag1'];
    $_SESSION['isb-vraag3'] = $_POST['isb-vraag3'];

?>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $strerror = "";
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag1']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br />";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag2']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag4']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag5']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag6']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag7']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."UU dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag8']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."UU dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag9']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag10']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag11']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag12']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag13']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag14']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag15']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag16']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag18']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($_POST['isb-vraag19']))
        {
            $strerror = $strerror."U dient deze vraag in te vullen<br/>";
        }
        if(strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag1']) != $_POST['isb-vraag1'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag3']) != $_POST['isb-vraag3'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag4']) != $_POST['isb-vraag4'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag5']) != $_POST['isb-vraag5'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag6']) != $_POST['isb-vraag6'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag7']) != $_POST['isb-vraag7'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag8']) != $_POST['isb-vraag8'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag9']) != $_POST['isb-vraag9'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag10']) != $_POST['isb-vraag10'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag11']) != $_POST['isb-vraag11'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag12']) != $_POST['isb-vraag12'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag13']) != $_POST['isb-vraag13'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag14']) != $_POST['isb-vraag14'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag15']) != $_POST['isb-vraag15'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag16']) != $_POST['isb-vraag16'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag17']) != $_POST['isb-vraag17'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag18']) != $_POST['isb-vraag18'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag19']) != $_POST['isb-vraag19'] || strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag20']) != $_POST['isb-vraag20'] || strip_tags($_POST['fm-lastname']) != $_POST['fm-lastname'] || strip_tags($_POST['fm-email']) != $_POST['fm-email'])
        {
            $$strerror = $strerror."Script is niet toegestaan<br/>";
        }
        if(empty($strerror))
        {
            $to = "test@company.nl";
            $subject = "Enquete Comany B.V.";
            $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
            $header .= "From: ".$_POST['fm-email']."\r\n";
            $header .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['fm-email'];
            $bericht = '
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Arial;">
        <div class="fm-req">
                <b><label for="fm-lastname">De volgende enquete is ingevuld door:</label></b><br/>
                <br/>
                '.$_POST['fm-lastname'].'
            </div>
        <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <b><label for="isb-vraag20">Afzender / Bedrijf:</label></b><br/>
                <br/>
                '.$_POST['isb-vraag20'].'
            </div><br/>
        <fieldset>
        <b><legend>De Antwoorden:</legend></b>
        <br/>
        <br/>
            <b><legend>Vraag 1:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag1">Waarom heeft u gekozen voor Company als leverancier?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag1'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 2:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag2">Koopt u ook bij andere leveranciers in de markt?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag2'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 3:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag3">Zo ja? Wat zijn de redenen en wat kunnen wij doen om u beter van dienst te zijn?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag3'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 4:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag4">Wat vindt u van onze telefonische bereikbaarheid?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag4'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 5:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag5">Wat is uw algemene indruk van onze verkoopafdeling?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag5'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 6:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag6">Wat is uw mening over de klantgerichtheid van onze verkoopafdeling?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag6'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 7:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag7">Wat vindt u van onze voorraad A-merken?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag7'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 8:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag8">Wat vindt u van onze voorraad B-merken?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag8'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 9:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag9">Wat vindt u van onze administratieve afhandeling / creditnota afhandeling?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag9'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 10:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag10">Wat vindt u van onze E-commerce website?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag10'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 11:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag11">Wat vindt u van onze bonusshop?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag11'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 12:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag12">Wat vindt u van onze bezoekfrequentie buitendienst medewerkers?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag12'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 13:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag13">Wat vindt u van de kwaliteit van deze bezoeken?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag13'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 14:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag14">Wat vindt u van de productondersteuning?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag14'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 15:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag15">Wat vindt u van onze uitleverprestatie / kwaliteit?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag15'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 16:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag16">Wat vindt u van de Company leveringen</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag16'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 17:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag17">Wat vindt u van de leveringen via Plaats? ( indien van toepassing )</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag17'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 18:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag18">Wat is uw algemene indruk / mening over ons bedrijf?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag18'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 19:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag19">Wat zou u graag veranderd willen zien, in onze organisatie?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag19'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <b><label for="isb-vraag20">Afzender / Bedrijf:</label></b><br/>
                <br/>
                '.$_POST['isb-vraag20'].'
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <b><label for="fm-lastname">Ingevuld door:</label></b><br/>
                <br/>
                '.$_POST['fm-lastname'].'
            </div>
        <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <b><label for="fm-email">E-mail</label></b><br/><br/>
                '.$_POST['fm-email'].'
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>';
            if(mail($to, $subject, $bericht, $header))
            {
                $to2 = $_POST['fm-email'];
                $subject2 = "Enquete succesvol ingevuld";
                $header2 = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $header2 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                $header2 .= "From: test@company.nl\r\n";
                $header2 .= "Reply-To: test@company.nl";
                $bericht2 = '
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Arial;">
        Hartelijk dank voor het invullen van deze enquete<br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Met vriendelijke groet,<br/>
        <br/> 
        <font style="font-weight: Bold">Company B.V.</font><br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Antwoorden:<br/>
        <br/>
        <fieldset>
        <b><legend>De Antwoorden:</legend></b>
        <br/>
        <br/>
            <b><legend>Vraag 1:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag1">Waarom heeft u gekozen voor Company als leverancier?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag1'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 2:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag2">Koopt u ook bij andere leveranciers in de markt?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag2'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 3:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag3">Zo ja? Wat zijn de redenen en wat kunnen wij doen om u beter van dienst te zijn?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag3'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 4:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag4">Wat vindt u van onze telefonische bereikbaarheid?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag4'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 5:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag5">Wat is uw algemene indruk van onze verkoopafdeling?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag5'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 6:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag6">Wat is uw mening over de klantgerichtheid van onze verkoopafdeling?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag6'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 7:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag7">Wat vindt u van onze voorraad A-merken?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag7'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 8:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag8">Wat vindt u van onze voorraad B-merken?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag8'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 9:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag9">Wat vindt u van onze administratieve afhandeling / creditnota afhandeling?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag9'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 10:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag10">Wat vindt u van onze E-commerce website?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag10'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 11:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag11">Wat vindt u van onze bonusshop?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag11'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 12:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag12">Wat vindt u van onze bezoekfrequentie buitendienst medewerkers?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag12'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 13:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag13">Wat vindt u van de kwaliteit van deze bezoeken?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag13'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 14:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag14">Wat vindt u van de productondersteuning?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag14'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 15:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag15">Wat vindt u van onze uitleverprestatie / kwaliteit?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag15'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 16:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag16">Wat vindt u van de company leveringen</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag16'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 17:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag17">Wat vindt u van de leveringen via Plaats? ( indien van toepassing )</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag17'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 18:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag18">Wat is uw algemene indruk / mening over ons bedrijf?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag18'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
                        <b><legend>Vraag 19:</legend></b>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="isb-vraag19">Wat zou u graag veranderd willen zien, in onze organisatie?</label>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <font color="red">'.$_POST['isb-vraag19'].'</font>
            </div>
            <br/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <b><label for="isb-vraag20">Afzender / Bedrijf:</label></b><br/>
                <br/>
                '.$_POST['isb-vraag20'].'
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <b><label for="fm-lastname">Ingevuld door:</label></b><br/>
                <br/>
                '.$_POST['fm-lastname'].'
            </div>
        <br/>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <b><label for="fm-email">E-mail</label></b><br/><br/>
                '.$_POST['fm-email'].'
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>';
                if(mail($subject2, $bericht2, $header2))
                {
                echo "\t\t\t\t\t<blockquote class=\"goed\">Hartelijk dank voor het invullen van de enquete.<br/></blockquote>\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "\t\t\t\t\t<blockquote>Uw enquete is niet correct verzonden, probeer het later opnieuw</blockquote>\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "\t\t\t\t\t<blockquote>" . $strerror . "</blockquote>\n";
            GetForm();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        GetForm();
    }

    function GetForm()
    {
?>  
                    <form name="aanvraag" method="post" action="index.php?action=checkform">
                    <fieldset>
                    <div>
                    <img width="300" height="108" alt="Company B.V." src="logogroot.png" style="float:right;">
                    <p>Geachte relatie, <br/><br/>
                    Company streeft er naar om de service aan haar klanten continu te verbeteren. <br/><br/>
                    Uw mening, als gewaardeerde klant, vinden wij hierin heel belangrijk. <br/>
                    Wat verwacht u van uw bandenleverancier, bent u tevreden of heeft u opbouwende kritiek. Wij vernemen het graag van u. <br/><br/>
                    Wij willen u dan ook vriendelijk verzoeken onderstaande vragen te beantwoorden en het ingevulde formulier 

                    </div>
                    </fieldset><br/>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Enquete Company B.V.</legend>
                            <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag1">Waarom heeft u gekozen voor Company als leverancier?</label><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['isb-vraag1'];?>" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag1"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag1']) == $_POST['isb-vraag1']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag1']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag2">Koopt u ook bij andere leveranciers in de markt?</label>
                                <br/><br/>
                                <input id="isb-vraag2" name="isb-vraag2" type="radio" value="Ja" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && $_POST['isb-vraag2'] == "Ja"){ echo "checked=\"checked\" "; } ?>style="width: 20px;"/> Ja
                                <input name="isb-vraag2" type="radio" value="Nee" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && $_POST['isb-vraag2'] == "Nee"){ echo "checked=\"checked\" "; } ?>style="width: 20px;" /> Nee
                            <br/>
                                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag3">Zo ja? Wat zijn de redenen en wat kunnen wij doen om u beter van dienst te zijn?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['isb-vraag3'];?>" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag3"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag3']) == $_POST['isb-vraag3']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag3']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag4">Wat vindt u van onze telefonische bereikbaarheid?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag4" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag4"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag4']) == $_POST['isb-vraag4']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag4']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag5">Wat is uw algemene indruk van onze verkoopafdeling?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag5" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag5"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag5']) == $_POST['isb-vraag5']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag5']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag6">Wat is uw mening over de klantgerichtheid van onze verkoopafdeling?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag6" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag6"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag6']) == $_POST['isb-vraag6']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag6']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag7">Wat vindt u van onze voorraad A-merken?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag7" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag7"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag7']) == $_POST['isb-vraag7']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag7']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag8">Wat vindt u van onze voorraad B-merken?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag8" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag8"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag8']) == $_POST['isb-vraag8']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag8']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag9">Wat vindt u van onze administratieve afhandeling / creditnota afhandeling?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag9" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag9"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag9']) == $_POST['isb-vraag9']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag9']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag10">Wat vindt u van onze E-commerce website?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag10" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag10"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag10']) == $_POST['isb-vraag10']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag10']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag11">Wat vindt u van onze bonusshop?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag11" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag11"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag11']) == $_POST['isb-vraag11']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag11']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag12">Wat vindt u van onze bezoekfrequentie buitendienst medewerkers?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag12" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag12"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag12']) == $_POST['isb-vraag12']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag12']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag13">Wat vindt u van de kwaliteit van deze bezoeken?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag13" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag13"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag13']) == $_POST['isb-vraag13']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag13']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag14">Wat vindt u van de productondersteuning?(Zoals folders etc)</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag14" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag14"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag14']) == $_POST['isb-vraag14']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag14']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag15">Wat vindt u van onze uitleverprestatie / kwaliteit?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag15" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag15"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag15']) == $_POST['isb-vraag15']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag15']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag16">Wat vindt u van de "Company" leveringen?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag16" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag16"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag16']) == $_POST['isb-vraag16']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag16']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag17">Wat vindt u van de leveringen via Plaats? (indien van toepassing)</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag17" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag17"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag17']) == $_POST['isb-vraag17']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag17']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag18">Wat is uw algemene indruk / mening over ons bedrijf?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag18" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag18"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag18']) == $_POST['isb-vraag18']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag18']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                                                        <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag19">Wat zou u graag veranderd willen zien, in onze organisatie?</label><br/><br/>
                                <textarea name="isb-vraag19" cols="60" rows="7" id="isb-vraag19"><?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag19']) == $_POST['isb-vraag19']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag19']; } ?></textarea>
                            </div><br/>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                        <div>
                        <p>U bent niet verplicht onderstaande bedrijfsgegevens in te vullen. Anoniem deelnemen mag ook. <br/><br/>
                        Wij stellen uw eerlijke antwoorden zeer op prijs en willen u vriendelijk danken voor uw tijd. <br/><br/>
                        Met vriendelijke groet, <br/>
                        Company B.V. <br/><br/><br/>
                        Door u als klant in te vullen.

                        </div><br/>
                            <div>
                                <label for="isb-vraag20">Afzender / Bedrijf:</label><br/><br/>
                                <input name="isb-vraag20" id="isb-vraag19" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['isb-vraag20']) == $_POST['isb-vraag20']){ echo $_POST['isb-vraag20']; } ?>" />
                            </div><br/>
                            <div>
                                <label for="fm-lastname">Ingevuld door:</label><br/><br/>
                                <input name="fm-lastname" id="fm-lastname" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['fm-lastname']) == $_POST['fm-lastname']){ echo $_POST['fm-lastname']; } ?>" />
                            </div><br/>
                            <div>
                                <label for="fm-email">E-mail:</label><br/><br/>
                                <input name="fm-email" id="fm-email" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Submitformk']) && strip_tags($_POST['fm-email']) == $_POST['fm-email']){ echo $_POST['fm-email']; } ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div id="fm-submit">
                            <input name="Submitform" value="Verstuur" type="submit" />
                        </div>
                    </form> 
<?php
    }
?>
```

And getting this error without submitting:

Notice: `Undefined index: isb-vraag1 in /company.nl/enquete/index.php on line 4`

Can somebody help my out?

Comment: `$_SESSION['isb-vraag1'] = $_POST['isb-vraag1'];` causing the problem because your form aren't submitted first before it transfer the value. In another words your form didn't send anything = No value, so cause undefined index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error means what it says. :-)

```
$_SESSION['isb-vraag1'] = $_POST['isb-vraag1'];
```

That simply mneans $_POST['isb-vraag1'] is not set.
This typically happens the first time you use your script.

Try this instead:

```
if (isset($_POST['isb-vraag1'])){
 $_SESSION['isb-vraag1'] = $_POST['isb-vraag1'];
} else {
  // do whatever you deem usefull. eg:
   $_SESSION['isb-vraag1'] = "";
}
```

Comment: @user1511766: Good. If there is one piece of advice I have for people just starting with forms and PHP it is using the function isset(). (And avoid SQL injection. And... well, good luck!)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to assign `$_POST` variables to `$_SESSION` variables without checking if they have been set.

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['isb_vraag1'])) {
  $_SESSION['isb-vraag1'] = $_POST['isb-vraag1'];
}
```